# Scraping an aspx website that uses cookies and login using python

Tags: python, http, pdf, cookies, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some pdfs from snl.com. I have a paid subscription and valid login credentials.

The url for one of the pdf files is  : http://www.snl.com/interactivex/file.aspx?Id=10735427&KeyFileFormat=PDF

After loggin in manually and accessing the above url, the actual url in the address bar when the pdf is rendered in browser is : [http://ofccolo.snl.com/Cache/44D87724CE10735427.PDF?CachePath=%5c%5cdmzdoc2%5cwebcache%24%5c&T=&O=PDF&Y=&D=](http://ofccolo.snl.com/Cache/44D87724CE10735427.PDF?CachePath=%5C%5Cdmzdoc2%5Cwebcache%24%5C&T=&O=PDF&Y=&D=)

When I access the url I'm redirected to `https://www.snl.com/interactivex/default.aspx` - a login page.

I have read several threads in SO about Python `requests` and tried the below code to get past the login page and handle cookies, but I still keep getting the login page as response which says : `"If you are already a registered SNL user, log in using your email address and password."`

```
import requests, sys
from requests.packages.urllib3 import add_stderr_logger

add_stderr_logger()
s = requests.Session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'

name_form = 'username'
password_form = 'Password'
login = {name_form: 'my_email_id', password_form: 'my_password'}
login_response = s.post("https://www.snl.com/interactivex/default.aspx", data=login)
print 'l',login_response
for r in login_response.history:
    if r.status_code == 401:  # 401 means authentication failed
        sys.exit(1)  # abort

pdf_response = s.get("http://www.snl.com/interactivex/file.aspx?Id=17670354&KeyFileFormat=PDF")
```

Output:

```
2014-06-26 13:04:54,555 DEBUG Added an stderr logging handler to logger: requests.packages.urllib3
2014-06-26 13:04:54,605 INFO Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.snl.com
2014-06-26 13:04:55,943 DEBUG "GET /interactivex/default.aspx HTTP/1.1" 302 152
2014-06-26 13:04:56,282 DEBUG "GET /interactivex/LoginCookieCheck.aspx HTTP/1.1" 302 143
2014-06-26 13:04:56,650 DEBUG "GET /interactivex/default.aspx HTTP/1.1" 200 None
2014-06-26 13:04:56,865 INFO Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.snl.com
2014-06-26 13:04:57,447 DEBUG "GET /interactivex/file.aspx?Id=17670354&KeyFileFormat=PDF HTTP/1.1" 302 143
2014-06-26 13:04:57,788 DEBUG "GET /InteractiveX/default.aspx HTTP/1.1" 302 162
2014-06-26 13:04:58,151 DEBUG "GET /InteractiveX/default.aspx HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

I don't know how to interpret this output but when I googled response code 200, I learnt that it means OK.

But when I print the pdf_response.text, it returns the login page again.

Comment: Have you tried doing a GET on the login page *first* to set the cookies that the POST handler for the login is looking for?

Comment: @Martijn Is this what you're talking about? s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'x-test': 'true'})  s.get('https://www.snl.com/interactivex/default.aspx', headers={'x-test2': 'true'})

Comment: @MartijnPieters I found the above peice of code on one of the SO posts. But it did me no good. Please let me know if there's a possible way to do it.

Comment: I don't know if there is any way to do it; there *probably* is but it depends entirely on the server and how it handles sessions, logins and specific headers in the request perhaps. Since this site requires a login that I don't have, I cannot replicate nor solve this specific problem.

Comment: I understand. Unfortuntely I am not allowed to share the credentials. Could you please guide me how I can get the required information for you as I login using my credentials from my browser?

Comment: You'd look at your browser development tools to see what requests are being made, and you make guesses as to what the server might want to have. The server is a black box, unless you speak to the developers of that server, all you can do is guess.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the tip. I have tried to get the info, here is the network activity that happens when I post the credentials and successfully login to the site : http://imgur.com/LEBksqU and the console log : http://imgur.com/ecSoIWm . Does it help?

Comment: @j-v: did you ever solve this problem?